# How to save a copy of SQL Server book online in my Android tablet?

Tags: ebooks

In SQL Server 2000 days, books online was in .chm format, and was very easy to save a copy on smart phones for reading. Now the new format is `.mshi` and `.mshc`, which can't be copied directly to an Android tablet for reading.

Is there a way to convert the book online into a format that can be read on Android system? Or is there a place that I can download some other format?

Comment: How to convert `.chm` files to a different format would seem to be independent of Android.

Comment: OP is asking about converting files from the new help format (MSHI or MSHC) to CHM or another format that's easily read on Android. Maybe a better question for SuperUser if Android is the wrong site?

Comment: I guess this question can also be read as "How can I read these books on my Android device", converting it to another format was just the fist thing coming to Yousui's mind, and other solutions might be welcome as well (@Yousui: please clarify!). If so, it's on-topic here. If not, it really is a better fit on another site.

Comment: Yes Izzy. Other solutions are welcome as well. Thank you guys!

Comment: Now that the question isn't on DBA.se anymore, it might be worth clarifying for anyone not familiar with SQL Server that 'Books Online' is the name for Microsoft's SQL Server documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has an eBook gallery available at http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/11608.e-book-gallery-for-microsoft-technologies.aspx

There's several slices from SQL Server Books Online there.